# Is there a regex that will put 10 digits (usually non-consecutive) into a named capturing group?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have a user input string that is supposed to contain at least 10 digits but they may be non-consecutive. Of these possible user inputs:

```
"What is 12? Can we 345 the loan to 678-90"
">>123456789--0"
"1234567890541112144847-909"
"Maybe try 123456 with 7890 too"
```

I want a regex to give me `match.groups.anyTen = '1234567890'`.

I have tried `/\d+/g` but I cannot combine the matches into a single named group. `/(?<anyTen>\d+/g` only names the first match of consecutive digits.

Other failures:

```
/(?<anyTen>\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*\d\D*)/
/(?<anyTen>\d{1,10})/
/(?<anyTen>\D*(\d\D*){10})/
```

Comment: This is phrased as an XY problem.  It's not necessary to produce a capture group with non-consecutive characters to achieve the result you want.  Some judicious use of `replace` to eliminate the unwanted characters, either before or after matching seems reasonable.  Perhaps your question should be reworded to state your string processing objective without committing to the use of regex.

Comment: @Wyck that's not a bad perspective but I wanted to get as far as possible with the regex and had thought that I was just missing something about using back references or some such. So, yes, a simple `.replaceAll(/\D/g,'').substring(0,9);` would have done it but then my regex knowledge would be stagnant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not have a single group that consists of non consecutive matches.

What you might do is match the first 10 digits, and then remove the non digits from it.

Note that `\D` also matches newlines.

If you want 10 or more digits, the quantifier will become `{9,}`

```js
const s = `"What is 12? Can we 345 the loan to 678-90"
">>123456789--0"
"1234567890541112144847-909"
"Maybe try 123456 with 7890 too"`;

const regex = /^[^\d\n]*(?<anyTen>\d(?:[^\d\n]*\d){9})/gm;
const result = Array.from(
  s.matchAll(regex), m =>
  m.groups.anyTen.replace(/\D+/g, "")
);
console.log(result)
```

Another option could be overwriting the value of the groups.anyVal property:

```js
const s = "What is 12? Can we 345 the loan to 678-90";
const regex = /^[^\d\n]*(?<anyTen>\d(?:[^\d\n]*\d){9})/;
const result = regex.exec(s);

if (result) {
  result.groups.anyTen = result.groups.anyTen.replace(/\D+/g, "");
  console.log(result.groups.anyTen);
}
```

Comment: These are both awesome and if I have to run 2 sequential regexes then that's fine, what's another 4 ms?  I had hoped that using back references could have taken the place of the post-processing step but I'm clearly not a regex-pert. Thanks!